# How to add Apple Push Notifications support to self hosted Parse server on Heroku?

Tags: ios, heroku, apple-push-notifications, parse-server

As Parse is shutting down I setup my own Parse server running on Heroku with this guide: https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example

However this does not support sending Apple push notifications.

How can I add support for sending push notifications?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been confirmed by the developers at Parse that they are working on adding Push Notifications for iOS & Android to the open source project. They plan to add it in the next month and they are also planning on adding the dashboard also within 2 months.

Confirmed here:
https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/56

If you need push sooner than that you could try using a 3rd party service such as Urban Airship.

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server/issues/5) for updates on when Parse will release push with dashboard.